# Assigning space for List<List<MyObj>>

Tags: java

I currently am trying to understand how Java assigns space when I ask it to.

Specifically (and as I am aware that I'm unable to declare an array with generics) I made this assignment:

```
List<List<Visitor>> elevlists;
elevlists = new ArrayList<List<Visitor>>(5);
```

as I want elevlists to be a list of 5 lists of Visitors. To my understanding this command will clear out space for five lists of Visitors and not have them there.

So I added this, which (and I underline) doesn't work:

```
List<Visitor> (elevlists.get(0)) = new ArrayList<Visitor>();
```

to see if I can actually create an instance for any of the lists.

But after some tweaking I ended to this code:

```
List<List<Visitor>> elevlists;
elevlists = new ArrayList<List<Visitor>>(5);
List<Visitor> temp = (elevlists.get(0));
temp = new ArrayList<Visitor>();
```

which, to my surprise, seems okay to the compiler.

Any help on why this is acceptable when the code above it isn't?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `ArrayList` at all. You just can't use a method call as the left hand side of an assignment. That is all. Btw: the second code might be ok for the compiler, but it will throw an Exception, because the list `elevlists` is empty and there is no index `0`. The compiler argument `5` doesn't create elements for the list.

Comment: Of course it is right for the compiler. You see, you just instantiated a `List` of lists with `elevlists`. However, each one of those lists need to be instantiated as well.

Comment: I noted that down, thanks Tom! Is my assignment right, though? Do I allocate the objects I want, or just clear space for them? @Luis Lavieri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList is not a array. It's a wrapper for array.

```
List<List<Visitor>> elevlists;
elevlists = new ArrayList<List<Visitor>>(5);
```

Here you just create a object ArrayList with 5 elements. But all elements inside this array is NULL.

Proper code should be:

```
List<List<Visitor>> elevlists;
elevlists = new ArrayList<List<Visitor>>(5);
List<Visitor> temp = new ArrayList<Visitor>();
elevlists.add(temp);
```

Comment: No it's not, proper code would be
List<Visitor> temp = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Because Java (implying java 7+) can infer the type by itself, and you should let it, that's the whole point of Generics.

Answer (score 0):

This is not doing what you think it is.

```
 List<Visitor> temp = (elevlists.get(0));
 temp = new ArrayList<Visitor>();
```

The second line affects only the variable temp, which now points to a newly allocated ArrayList.

Read this as

```
 get the value stored at element zero (which is currently null) in elevlists, assign that value to temp.

 now throw away that value in temp, and instead make temp point to a new Array List
```

If you want to make elevlists have some non-null values use

```
elevlists.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, although your second code will compile, it will fail at runtime because the `elevlists = new ArrayList<List<Visitor>>(5);` does not actually create elements in `elevLists` - the 5 is just a hint to the ArrayList class how much space to reserve.  ArrayList is an array wrapper and doesn't reserve memory for an array in the same way as, say, C.

@Tom is right in comments - the first example doesn't compile because you can't have method calls on the LHS of assignments.

Comment: I'll look into array wrappers. It's true, though, that's what's happening in runtime.